# How to determine data size created by sensor for calculation of signal processing and transmitting over wireless communication?

Tags: robotics, signal-processing, signal, radar

I want to build some sort of SAR sensor. Since radar works high speeds and creates loads of data this should be processed faster. I am trying to find algorithms to be used for this purpose. I am at the beginning of the project so just looking around some information. I haven't had much progress yet.

I have some values in mind such as, what frequency I will use, what bandwidth I will have, what sampling frequency will I have and how many channels etc. Then I will process them. Preferably in real-time. But I am not familiar with the way how the storage capacity and processing speed needed can be calculated for this. I want to decide whether I need to use onboard (battery powered unmanned vehicle) computation or I need to send raw data to ground-station and doing all the processing in it. If so don't know if something Nvidia Xavier would be handy or standard windows installed pc would be good for this purpose.

Example scenario like this, I have a base-band signal at 10MHz and will be swept by upconverting to RF signal and received back following to downconversion back to 10MHz. Then Quadrature mixer will allow me to find the phase shift. If I am not wrong I need to sample this data at a frequency like 50MHz. This will create 50 million samples I and Q in a second for each, thus the total of 10 million data point. This is one-dimensional data. This will be scanned in a spatial direction to yield 2D radar image which should then be processed. I don't know how big will this data be and if I will be able to process it in almost real time.

I am looking for some hints or some experienced advice.

Comment: So, you want an algorithm for data that you can't specify, frequency & bandwidth you don't know, no sampling rate or the number of channels... This has to be too broad.

Comment: Not actually, sorry for non native english, ı have my radar frequency ans bandwidth values so the sampling frequency. This should result overall data point created in a second. Right? But ı don't know how to calculate storage and communication or processing speed ı need to process that data

Comment: I dont know which technology will suffice.

Comment: Please give us all of the details that you have.  If you already know the bandwidth, or number of channels, please say that.  Even if it is an estimate or a range.  As it is, this question is so broad that it's impossible to answer.  What is "high speed" to one person may be extremely slow to someone else.  What is "loads of data" to one person may be nothing at all to someone else.  We need to know more about what you are working on to begin to give you any help.